# JavaFX: CheckMenuItem not showing clear square

Tags: css, javafx, menuitem

I'm hand-coding an FXML file and the CheckMenuItem's little box is invisible when deselected. For the longest time I thought the CheckMenuItem tag wasn't working because there wasn't a white square just empty space. I'm assuming there is a CSS way to fix this but I can't find how anywhere.

Comment: Looks like you can target the check's container with `.check-menu-item > .left-container { ... }`.

Comment: [mcve] please ...